# css toggle with sign of + and -

Tags: css, toggle

I have done with the pure css toggle and working fine. **Now I have also put a code when toggle is active it end shows + sign and when its clicked and open it shows sign-. Same when its closed it must shows + sign.** Please help me if you guys have any idea. I have attached example image and code.  here is the image for example (http://highercodetechnologies.com/New_benners/tg.png) check out **+ and - sign**

Thank you

Code....

```
/* Clean up the lists styles */
ul.accordion {
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

/* Hide the radio buttons */
/* These are what allow us to toggle content panes */
ul.accordion label + input[type='radio'] {
  display: none;
}

/* Give each content pane some styles */
ul.accordion li {
background-color: #ffffff;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
}

/* Make the main tab look more clickable */
ul.accordion label {
background-color: #33abde;
color: #FFFFFF;
display: block;
padding: 10px;
font-weight:bold;
}

ul.accordion label:hover {
cursor: pointer;
}

    /* Set up the div that will show and hide */
   ul.accordion div.content {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 10px;
    display: none;
   }

  /* Show the content boxes when the radio buttons are checked */( here I tried to do     
   that but not working.)
   ul.accordion label + input[type='radio']:checked + div.content {
  display: block;
  }

Html code

  <ul class='accordion'>
  <li>
  <label for='cp-1'>Content pane 1</label>
  <input type='radio' name='a' id='cp-1' checked='checked'>
  <div class='content'>
      <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac      
  turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit 
 amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae 
 est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
  </div>
 </li>

 <li>
  <label for='cp-2'>Content pane 2</label>
  <input type='radio' name='a' id='cp-2'>
  <div class='content'>
      <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac 
 turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet,   
 ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. 
 Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
  </div>
  </li>

<li>
   <label for='cp-3'>Content pane 3</label>
  <input type='radio' name='a' id='cp-3'>
  <div class='content'>
      <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac 
   turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit        
  amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae 
  est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
  </div>
  </li>
```

Comment: And you suppose we will just write this for you and **for free**?

Comment: http://www.menucool.com/vertical/accordion-menu-css

Answer (score 1):

Hmm this line of code

```
  ul.accordion label + input[type='radio']:checked + div.content {
      display: block;
  }
```

doesn't look right. The `+` is an [adjacent sibling selector](http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/). But the `input` and the `div.content` are not siblings but children of the `ul.accordion`.

Try to change that declaration for something like

```
input[type='radio']:checked + .content {
    display: block
}
```

Also, if possible try not to be so specific with your selectors. For example, using `.content` instead of `div.content` will allow your css to work if your HTML markup changes a bit and you have some other tag instead of a `div` with the class `.content`.

Answer (score 0):

One way is as simple as this:

```
ul.accordion div.content:after {
    content: '+';
}

ul.accordion label + input[type='radio']:checked + div.content:after {
    content: '-';
}
```

Of course, you can style it and place it like you want to.

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/VtRCR/)